# Environment variables won't take effect on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables

I've been trying back and forth to set environment variables in the Terminal.app but it won't take any effect.

Here's the scenario: With the Terminal open I write

```
pico .profile
```

Then in the editor I enter

```
export JAVA_HOME="Library/Java/Home"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then I press `ctrl+x` to exit and `y` to save. I exit the terminal and when I open it up again and write

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I only get an empty line. Can I edit the `.profile` in another way? I've tried every possible combination to set this variable but I keep getting an empty line. I have restarted the system several times with no luck at all.

Comment: It sounds like the `.profile` file is not being used. Are you sure it is `~/.profile` that is being modified? And the permissions are correct? (I am not sure what shell OS X uses by default, but here is the [relevant section in bash](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files).)

Comment: i just noticed that every time i save the .profile generates a new file every time i save and names it **profile.save.2** and the number increases as i keep saving it. I don't think that's right. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the output of: cat .profile ?

Comment: i wrote **cat .profile** and i got **No such file or directory** i'm i doing something wrong?

Comment: By the way, this was working when i had Leopard as soon as i updated the operative system to OSX Lion the problem started happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by editing the `~/.bash_profile` instead.

When you use `pico .profile` instead of editing the file, which will make a new file, I chose "read file" (I think it is `ctrl=r`) and it showed me a lot of files. From there I chose `.bash_profile`.

That was my solution. I don't know if it's the best solution but it worked for me.

Comment: If `~/.bash_profile` exists, bash **will not read** `~/.profile`. So whatever you write in there won't ever be parsed.